# Delete entity with non-nullable foreign key relationship entity framework 5 POCO

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have a one to many relationship with a non nullable foreign key column on the child entity. I'm trying to delete a record from the child table but can't seem to get it to work.

I end up with a message similar to the following - A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: A primary key property that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be changed when the dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set to the association's principal object. The principal object must be tracked and not marked for deletion

I am attempting to delete the object just by calling context.Set().Remove(entity)...

I have tried removing the entity from the parent collection and then deleting it before calling save changes. I have also tried just deleting the child entity directly but no matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to work.

What is the proper way of deleting a child entity that has a non-nullable foreign key relationship in entity framework 5?

Here is my mapping configuration :

[image: Entity Mapping]

This works --

```
var item = this.unitOfWork.PersonalListItemRepository.GetFirst(x => x.PersonalListID == 45146 && x.ItemCode == "1030943" && x.UOM == "EA");
        this.unitOfWork.PersonalListItemRepository.Delete(item);
```

The delete implementation is simply --

```
this.context.Set<T>().Remove(item);
```

However this will not work --

```
var listToUpdate =
this.unitOfWork.PersonalListRepository.FindByExpression(
    x => x.PersonalListID == personalList.PersonalListID).First();
var entityToDelete = listToUpdate.PersonalListItems.First();

this.unitOfWork.PersonalListItemRepository.Delete(entityToDelete);
```

Implementation of FindByExpression --

```
 public ICollection<T> FindByExpression(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Where(expression).ToList();
    }
```

I have also tried to remove the item from the parent entities collection and just update the parent. I suppose I can, once I've gotten the list if children I need to delete, reload them from the context and then delete them (but this seems like it is unnecessary being that the items were loaded from my context to begin with). I must be missing something major here...

Comment: Are you sure the relationship is configured as one to many? How did you configure that? I think this relationship is configured as one to one in EF.

Comment: @nhrobin I am 100% positive this is configured as a one to many relationship. These particular entities were generated from an existing database model.

Comment: Using `context.Set<T>().Remove(entity)` is correct. If it doesn't work the devil is in the details - which would be helpful to see in your question (entities, mapping configuration, your actual code that loads/attaches entities and that attempts to delete, etc.)

Comment: To add a bit more information, it seems that if I load an entity from the child table directly (not from the parent collection as a lazy loaded item) and remove it, there is no issue.

Comment: Does `FindByExpression` query with `AsNoTracking()`?

Comment: @Slauma Not to my knowledge? I'll update with the simple implementation of that method.

Comment: Is the `context` instance the same in both repositories?

Comment: @Slauma Yeap it is injected in when the UnitOfWork is created...

Comment: @Slauma I think I may have found the problem.... :( So, what was happening when I grab the "first" entity to delete it converted the entity from a proxy to a pure poco thus why the first sample worked but when I do any sort of "linq" operation to get the entities to update, they are no longer the Proxies thus the context knows nothing about them... Does anyone know how to keep them as proxies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem here ended up being that the items that I ended up trying to delete (or modify/attach to the context) were not the proxies that were pulled from the original query to the database. So, the entity framework was complaining because it though I was trying to modify the primary key of an entity it was already tracking with a new entities value (the exception, although correct, was misleading).

The solution here is to make certain that I am not trying to attach or update with a non-proxy entity when the context has already started tracking a proxy version of the same entity.